# How to disable Hazelcast

Tags: logging

I am using Hazelcast in my project, it auto-starts every time the application is deployed. Is there any way to disable the autostart mechanism.

I want it to start manually when needed.

Problems:

1. Causes performance waste
2. ***HEAVILY*** Bloats Log files

Please suggest